# Why does this work in DrRacket but not in Racket from the console? (R: undefined;)

Tags: racket

This code tests port connectivity. Why does this work in DrRacket but not in **Racket from the console** or in the **executable** (Racket -> Create Executable...)?

```
#lang racket
(require racket/tcp)
(define (tcp-open? host port)
  (with-handlers ((exn:fail:network? (lambda (e) #f)))
    (define-values (inp outp) (tcp-connect host port))
    (close-input-port inp)
    (close-output-port outp)
    #t))
```

works fine in DrRacket:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.2 [3m].
Language: racket [custom]; memory limit: 512 MB.
> (tcp-open? "www.racket-lang.org" 80)
#t
```

The error message from the console is:

```
Welcome to Racket v5.3.2.
> (require racket/tcp)
> (define (tcp-open? host port)
  (with-handlers ((exn:fail:network? (lambda (e) #f)))
    (define-values (inp outp) (tcp-connect host port))
    (close-input-port inp)
    (close-output-port outp)
    #t))
> (tcp-open? "www.racket-lang.org" 80)
R: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
  context...:
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\private\misc.rkt:87:7
```

Comment: Works for me at the commandline. I tested in Racket v6.0.0.1 and v5.3. Can you include the exact steps you are using to run this at the commandline?

Comment: I edited the question. Isn't 5.3.6 the latest version?

Comment: Asumu, this looks very suspiciously like the persistent Windows bug that Tim Nelson reported a few years ago.  Looking for the reference... http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.racket.user/1759

Comment: Not just in pasting, in generated executable too. I think it is because of no proper handling of \r in Windows. (read-line) has a bug too.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm on Linux so I didn't see the problem. @KIMTaegyoon can you try the same program with a pre-release version of Racket v6.0? (from here: http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/snapshots/) If the bug exists in the pre-release too, please submit a bug report.

Comment: @AsumuTakikawa My program works fine in pre-release Racket v6.0.0.1. Thank you.

Comment: It might be a good idea to answer this question saying that it was a bug and is fixed in the latest version of racket. (So this question shows up as answered.)